# Considering getting a computer science job just before graduating from mechanical engineering

Tags: job-change

I am going to soon graduate from mechanical engineering but have realized that I would rather do a job in computer science or computer engineering, although I did fairly well in mechanical engineering and found several courses interesting. I am considering enrolling in related courses offered as open electives by my university to explore subjects of interest to me such as algorithms and machine learning further. But these courses would take up a significant amount of time over 3-4 months and I would probably not be able to get a job during that time as a result. The courses are fully online but the job timings may conflict with those for the course assessments and lectures, which may not be recorded. I have no internship or job experience in computer science/engineering.

Is this a good idea or should I first aim to get a job in mechanical engineering and prepare for interviews for IT positions on the side? There a number of online training programs and courses, interview preparation videos, and websites with coding questions I could practice independently to prepare for interviews. Are there any other paths I could explore?

Comment: we really can't tell you if its a good idea to try to get a Computer Science job instead of a Mechanical Engineering one.

Comment: What's a "computer science" job? That field covers a lot of disciplines.

Comment: "**these courses would take up a significant amount of time over 3-4 months**". Do you plan to take bootcamp programming courses ? - In addition, have you looked into **Leetcode style coding** questions ? Nowadays, not all but many companies ask this kind of coding questions during the interviews for a programer job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am going to soon graduate from mechanical engineering but have realized that I would rather do a job in computer science or computer engineering

I also did not graduate in computer science, STEM nonetheless, and got my first job (without past internships or work experience) in the computer science area anyway.

In university we get in closer contact with several knowledge fields, and we can better gauge what kind of job we'd prefer than we could 5 years ago choose a university course.

So, by all means, I think you should *eventually* go for a IT job instead of wasting time in a temporary job. But *when*?

Well, the chances of being hired without proven experience in the area are slim. Have you conducted extracurricular research projects in the computation area while an undergraduate? Do you have an history of contributing to relevant open-source projects? In a nutshell, do you have **facts** to convince interviewers that you **have gone out of your way** to perfect your skills as a software developer (or whatever else job you want in computer science area)?

If the answer is yes, then go for it. If not, you have to find ways to fill this gap. You propose some,

> online training programs and courses, interview preparation videos, and websites with coding questions

but perhaps only the first will give you actual verifiable experience in the area. The second is a bit waste of time, and the last can be useful at the start of the learning process, but not beyond that point, I'd argue. Look instead into what I've suggested in the 4th paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Mechanical engineer here who recently switched to software development.

In my opinion, 3-4 months of post graduation course work isn't enough time for you to become proficient in software development. It simply just takes longer to learn it and become good at it.

If you haven't graduated yet and you don't have any job offers in hand yet, is it possible to declare a 2nd major at your university?

If you already close to obtaining your ME degree, you probably have 75% of the prerequisites for a CS degree. If you are willing to spend an extra few semesters at the University (and perhaps even get an development internship), most companies would look favorable upon the CS degree rather than a few courses taken afterwards post graduation.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you instead of declaring a second major do a master's degree in computer engineering or computer science? Are you likely to be accepted into a related program?

Answer (score 1):

I have a mechanical engineering degree, but changed to a career in electronics and computing. The change wasn't easy; if you have a specific degree, then most employers will assume that is where your skills lie. If you also have work experience in that area, then it cements the idea that this is what you are: a mechanical engineer.

The way I escaped was to build up a portfolio of software projects in my spare time, then sought a job in a small business, that had no problem hiring people without specific computing qualifications. It took many years to make the career transition, so I wouldn't recommend this approach

So I'd suggest you take the plunge sooner rather than later. It is a bit risky, and may stretch your finances, but the longer you leave the decision, the harder it will be to make the change - and in my personal opinion, computing is much more interesting than mechanical engineering (especially thermodynamics - ugh!).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine them.

There is a lot of IT work to be done in ME teams: Managing the CAD systems, drawings, interfacing with version control, production and manufacturing control systems, pulling BOMs, configuring parts data bases, connect with EE CAD systems, providing Gerber outlines, work flow management, and on and on.

This type of work is often a bit of an orphan and many ME teams would love to have dedicated resource for this type thing.

There maybe other ways combining both.